# Chain requests to the server in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

Let's say I need to make two async calls to different API endpoints. Query parameters of second call depend on what I receive from the first one

Quick overview:

- First endpoint provides some ids in specific order (sorted by rating, for example)
- Second endpoint provides some "meta information" about those ids

Endpoint examples:

**GET/endpoint/one**

response format:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    rating: 0.67
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    rating: 0.51
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    rating: 0.45
  },
  ...
]
```

**GET/endpoint/two?id=1,2**

```
// I receive those ids from call to the first endpoint
```

response format:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    gender: "male",
    age: 20,
    profession: "Programmer"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    gender: "transgender",
    age: 27,
    profession: "ML Engineer"
  }
]
```

Afterwards I need to loop through the all the ids I have and display meta info in my template, but order should be the same as it was in response of the **endpoint/one**

I decided to crate a key: val storage for those needs, i.e:

```
const storage = {
  1: {
    gender: "male",
    age: 20,
    profession: "programmer"
  }
}
```

also I have a variable with persons from first endpoint, i.e:

```
const persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    rating: 0.67
  },
  ...
]
```

so in my template I could do smth like

```
<p v-for="p in persons">{{ storage[p.id].gender }}</p>
```

The question is: how I could chain my requests to have all the data available after I call some function, which initiates my requests?

*Keep in mind that I could query the second endpoint only with two ids, so I will need to loop through the list of ids I have and make a separate call for each one. In a real app I have ~ 100 ids from the first endpoint, so I need to make ~ 50 calls to the second one

Comment: you want your answer to include vuex example?

Comment: Once you receive the list of ids, you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to make sure you have all the data before proceeding. Smarter would be to declare mutations for adding ids, and render them as they come.

Comment: Side note: "transgender" is not a gender. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25826/how-can-i-deal-with-diverse-gender-identities-in-user-profiles

Comment: @ceejayoz thx for a clarification! Since I'm really confused with things happening around (touching this trans stuff)

Comment: @HackingNode Yeah, it can be confusing, and it's good that you're trying to consider transgender people in your UX decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/lucaskatayama/qxyn1rp1/3/

Actually, that is not a VueJS problem. That is a async problem solved by **Promises**, or **Callbacks**, ou **Async/Await** in Javascript.

In my example, I solved using Promises.

There I simulate requests creating a Timeout and returning a Promise when it is done. `Axios` do the same thing.

When a Promise resolves you can chain by using a `.then` and passing another function to call the second request. and then and then and then.

Inside the `then`you can use the response as you wish, creating another request based on the returned data, requesting another list, etc.

To do with a lot of requests, I prefer using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to limit the number of request per time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried it in my real app, but now I have issues with looping through the list in my template (Looks like loop starts at the same time with requests and throws %property% is undifined). Button click initiates the requests. If I press button two times - it renders the content, as I understand because on the second click everything is defined ;)

* I can't use created hook, since in the real app I need to pass an id to the first request

Comment: Ok.. instead of having a component with v-for, iterating over a list and fetching, you could have a component with a list of child components, and each child one could fetch when it was created.